# set of two input files in one command

Tags: linux

I have a two set of files set one has 20 files and set two also has 20 files. I need to run a command that will take 1st file from set 1 and 1st file from set two and perform the command and gives one output file. I am unable to pick the 1st file from set one and the 1st file from set two exactly at same time.

command input_file_1 input_file_2 output

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `sed` to print the nth line of a file. Since you know that both files have 20 lines, you can dump them both and then print the 1st and 11th, 2nd and 12th line and so on. The result can be fed into `xargs`. Like so (this is `bash`): `for i in 1 2 3 4; do cat file1 file2 | sed -n -e "$i"p -e $(expr $i + 20)p | xargs echo; done`. Maybe not the most elegant way but it works. If you want something less obscure then read both files into an array and iterate over the two arrays simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two sets in arrays, then use a loop that indexes both arrays.

```
set1=("file1" "file2" "file3" ...)
set2=("fileA" "fileB" "fileB" ...)
for ((i=0; i<${#set1[@]}; i++))
do
    command "${set1[$i]}" "${set2[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess it will work. I am trying this!